# How to get the x, y axis location of the view itself in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, javascript

How to get the x, y-axis location of the view itself in selenium?

I know I can get the position of a specific element. But I can't find a way to get the coordinate of the window's view itself. So I can see it change as a scrolling/click action in the page happened.

Are there ways to do that in Selenium?

I uses `wd.js`

Comment: I answered my similar question in SO here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41227777/check-if-the-view-is-on-the-top-of-the-screen-with-selenium-javascript-web-drive

Comment: I think this is legitimately on-topic for SQA.  Could you transpose the answer here?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the below snippet:

```
Point point = element.getLocation();

int x_co_ordinate = point.getX();
int y_co_ordinate = point.getY();

System.out.print(x_co_ordinate + ", " + y_co_ordinate);
```

Comment: it's more about view rather than the element itself. thanks